# Unit test for struct initialization in C

Tags: c, testing

I would like to write a test for a routine of data structure initialization. E.g.,

```
struct book_t
{
   float price;
   int page_num;
   char title[100];
   int hardcover:1;
   int on_sale:1;
   int language:3;
}

void init_book(struct book_t *b)
{
    /* use memset or assign value to each field */
};
```

A test of init_book() would be helpful to prevent a developer from forgetting to update init_book() if they modify struct book_t.  It is not helpful to check the field values one by one, since new fields would not be tested.

I am considering using some sort of Boolean operation for this case, but it is insufficient to determine uninitialized fields from padding. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Adding new fields cannot be check for by unit testing.

This should be done by code review.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider adding a hard coded struct size validation in the end of the init function, and whoever adds a parameter and haven't updated the hard coded size compared to the struct size will be asserted in the first run